# What is truncation in C++?

Tags: c++, truncated

I'm having my code compiled successfully, in most of the cases it works perfectly well, but on some cases containing long and great numbers of inputs to my array the result turns into something strange and minus, and the compiler shows 'truncated' in front of the last input. What is wrong with it? When does this happen?[image]

Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, index, max, deletion;
    cin>>n;
    int ar[n];
    long long freq[100]={0};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin>>ar[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        index=ar[i];
        freq[index]++;
    }
    max=freq[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
    {
        if(max < freq[i])
        {
            max=freq[i];
        }
    }
    deletion=n-max;
    cout<<deletion<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not something your code does, or your compiler. Most likely, whatever site you use to run the code just refuses to fully print long output.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh I see...

Comment: If you want help with the difference of the desired output above (I guess that is what it is) and your output below, then you need to provide more details.  E.g. a [mre] of your code and a description of what it should do.

Comment: Please read https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/ and/or https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @Yunnosch What my code does is to input an int from the user (n) and create an array with (n) number of indexes. It then has to evaluate the min number of removement in the array to result in same values. Example: [1,3,3,4] --> If i remove 1 and 4, my array will have same value of 3 for all. And this is the min number of removes I can do, which is 2. I'm also gonna post my code above :)

Comment: @WernerHenze I understand. I'm really sorry for this :( I simply thought my question was general enough and didn't need any more detailed thing. I've added my code to my post and there's a short description in the commets of what I expect my code to do. Sorry again for not being clear enough at first

Comment: `int ar[n];` is not valid C++. And as already said: please don't post images of text, post text. Your program crashes if numbers read into `ar` are >=100. Are you sure that you don't run into such a case? Your last loop is accessing `freq[100]`, that is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @WernerHenze The challenge is precised for 1 <= n <= 100 and 1 <= ar[i] <= 100